# Steam Key for in game Items

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam

I am developing a game in Unity and am seeking to integrate Steam key activation for in-game items. Is this feasible, and if so, what kind of access from the game owner would be required to implement this functionality?

[image]

I am facing difficulty in determining the necessary access required to implement Steam key activation in a Unity game as I currently do not have any access to the game. Could you please advise on the type of access I should request from the game owner?

Answer (score 2):

You need access to Steam's back-end to generate the keys, and then you need to program a connection with Steam's API into the game to look up whether those keys have been redeemed or not.

Steam has to have a record of the game already, so you have to have already paid the fee to create the game record after your Steam developer account is approved.  Then refer to the Steam Developer docs regarding how to generate keys and integrate the API.